# Converting an Array of Hexadecimal Strings to Numbers

Tags: javascript, hex, typed-arrays

I have an application in which a server is sending a lot of data every second to clients that request it.  In this data set are several (large) arrays that contain numbers (in some cases 16-bit integers and in others double precision floats).  In order to reduce the packet size, I would like to send only the number of bytes that are necessary to represent the number (2 bytes for the 16 bit and 8 for the 64 bit).  I know that I can do something like this:

```
/* Create space for 4 32 bit numbers */
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(16);

/* Hex representation of [0, 123, 246, 369] */
buffer = ["0x0", 0x7B", "0xF6", "0x171"];

/* Actual array containing numbers above */
var int32View = new Int32Array(buffer);
```

but....I don't want to prepend everything sting with "0x" (adding two bytes will double the size of the 16 bit numbers).  I think I might be missing something - is there a better way to do this such that I don't need to indicate that the strings are hexadecimal representations of numbers (i.e. can I drop the "0x")?

Thanks, Matt

Comment: How are you transmitting the data? As a string or as binary?

Comment: If you're parsing it yourself, I guess you could do whatever you want. For example, you could just leave off the 0x and look for a decimal point to determine whether it's a float. Or just prepend "x" and look for that. The sky's the limit, really.

Comment: `["0x0", "0x7B", "0xF6", "0x171"].map(Number) ==  ["0", "7B", "F6", "171"].map(function(a){return parseInt(a,16);})`

Comment: You won't be able to convert 64-bit representation of floats from string as JS does not have 64-bit integers (yet/es7). You would have to use a big-int library for that (your example is also overwriting the typed array with a plain array). You have to split out the values, then convert them to typed arrays. For the floats, first to a 32-bit signed array, use the resulting buffer as source for Float32 (64-bit need special treatment).

Comment: @Pete - the data is being transmitted as a JSON string. I want to minimize the size of the array (i.e. I don't want to use 5 bytes for something that might be represented as 2).  On the server side, what I can do is convert the numbers to a hex representation, but I don't want to have to append "0x" as 1) this would be computationally expensive and 2) it impacts the size of the data transmitted.

Comment: @K3N - I am not following you.  There is a [Float64 typed array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Float64Array); is there a reason this can not be used?

Comment: @JayArby - Ha!  I wish! Actually, the sky is not the limit as there are computational limitations since we have a fixed amount of time to do all of this.

Comment: @Matt if you receive a 64-bit float represented as hex, it will be represented as ieee768, or 0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, but in integer, which cannot be interpreted directly in JS. You would have to store two parts high-end and low-end 32-bit to a uint32 first using two indexes (making sure byte-order is correct), then use that buffer for a float64array view.

Comment: @Matt unless the numbers are received as "2.012", "-1.33" string etc. of course, but these wouldn't be hex-numbers (this part is not clear though from the Q as there is no example of floats). If literal representations it is not difficult to convert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use map() or a for-loop to treat each value and use the length as basis for where to sort them out.

One note though, you mention 64-bit floats. When these are extracted from a buffer they will be 64-bit integer values (ie. 0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX) formatted in IEEE-754 format.

However, JavaScript can only work with 32-bit values (0xXXXXXXXX) so you have to split the processing of those into two parts using a 32-bit unsigned array, then add a Float64Array view for that later.

If the float values are literals, ie "2.345", "-1.33" etc. then you can simply use `parseFloat(str)` on them (instead of handling 64-bit values as below).

## Example

```js
// inserted 64-bit IEEE float of -2.3357 = 0x7b4a233ac002af83
var normArray = ["0", "7B", "F6", "7b4a233ac002af83", "171"],
    int16a = [], int32a = [],
    int16b, int32b, float64b;

normArray.map(function(entry) {
  if (entry.length > 4) {
    var high = entry.substr(0, 8),
        low = entry.substr(8, 8);
    int32a.push(parseInt(high, 16), parseInt(low, 16));
  }
  else {
    int16a.push(parseInt(entry, 16));
  }
});

// convert to typed arrays
int16b = new Int16Array(int16a);
int32b = new Uint32Array(int32a);
float64b = new Float64Array(int32b.buffer); // convert IEEE rep. to floats

document.writeln("<pre>int16  : " +
                int16b[0] + ", " + int16b[1] + ", " + int16b[2] + ", ...");
document.write("float64: " + float64b[0] + "</pre>")
```

Comment: Thanks, K3N...Good solution for the floating point numbers.  After running some tests, it looks like using `parseInt()` is not as expensive as I thought it would be.